# Creating a Drag and Drop game

Tags: c#, wpf, drag, textblock

I'm creating a game that first requires the user to drag a certain textblock into a rectangle. Depending on which textblock is dropped into the rectangle, I want to store the contents of that specific textblock. It's important to note: I want the values stored ***only when*** the textblock is dropped inside the rectangle.

**The problem**: How can I make it so the computer knows that the rectangle contains the textblock?

Here's a screenshot to make things a little more clear: http://gyazo.com/3aa3a8678f11260889261fcd46366616.png

As of now, I can drag and drop the textblock fine, but the computer has no way of knowing if the textblock and rectangle intersect. 
I've been trying to solve this problem for a few days now, and have spent a lot of time trying to use the system.drawing.rectangle.IntersectsWith()...only to find out that you can't dynamically add a system.drawing.rectangle to the canvas.

I've also thought of doing it by coordinates: if(textblock's coordinates are within the bounds of the rectangles coordinates)... However, I've spent time trying to figure out how to dynamically get the coordinate position of a xaml control, only to find out that you can't.

**Could someone please offer some guidance?** I've been working hard towards this and I've hit a dead end, so any degree of help will be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16570494/643085

Comment: WPF, WinForms, HTML ?

Comment: HighCore, I'm not sure if I understand your solution. I don't see how the computer recognizes the cells being in a certain area. I appreciate the help though.  Henk, WPF.

Comment: @user2554672 Did you run the example? WPF has built-in drag and drop capabilities, you don't need to handle that yourself.

Comment: Can you expand upon that? And I can't run the example, but I looked at it and can sort of see what it does.

Comment: @user2554672 is it giving you any errors? just let me know, maybe I forgot to include some pieces of the code. WPF supports dragging and dropping via the  `DragDrop` class and the `Drop` events and so on.